# Half of Page is linked (highlighted on mouse over) when not supposed too?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hyperlink

I have the strangest problem that I have never encountered before, nor was able to find any explanation too. The first section of my page works like normal (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KuzU.jpg). But the next section of my page acts like a clickable link or button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/noqmx.jpg). When clicking anywhere on this section it scrolls back to the top. Obviously, this is not wanted. Any help would be awesome!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Bootsrap With Flexbox Grid -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
        <!-- Google Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400|Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- icons -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- My CSS -->
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-------------------     HEADER     --------------------->

        <section id="header">

            <nav>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <img src="/img/logoblack.png" alt="Temple Naylor logo" class="logo">
                            <ul class="main-nav">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Skill</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Résumé</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Writing</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <div class="container header">

                <div class="row hello">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">Hello I'm</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row name">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">Temple Cerulean Naylor</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row job">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">Web Developer  /  UX/UI Designer</div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary lets-talk">Let's Talk</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down scroll" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>

        <!-------------------     ABOUT     --------------------->

        <section id="about">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="me">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="img/me.png" alt="me">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
                        <p>Hello</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>



        <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-BLiI7JTZm+JWlgKa0M0kGRpJbF2J8q+qreVrKBC47e3K6BW78kGLrCkeRX6I9RoK" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/* -------------------------------------
          HEADER
--------------------------------------*/
#header {
    background:  url('/img/header.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}
.main-nav {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 55px;
}

.main-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.main-nav li a:link,
.main-nav li a:visited {
    padding: 8px 0;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 120%;
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: border-bottom 0.2s;
    }

.main-nav li a:hover,
.main-nav li a:active {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #2980b9;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 2%;
}

.header {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;

    font-weight: 300;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}

.hello {
    font-size: 200%;
    padding-top: 5%;
}

.name {
    font-size: 350%;
}

.job {
    font-size: 210%;
}

.lets-talk {
    margin-top: 6%;
    font-size: 150%;
}

.scroll {
    font-size: 250%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    color: black;
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.scroll:hover {
    color: #2980b9;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Edit: I apologize for the bad quality pictures. When taking a screenshot of my screen it will not print the mouse (which I am trying to show the problem). Instead I had to take pictures with my phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close a link (`a`) tag on this line:

```
<p ><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down scroll" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
```

Everything from the opening `<a href="#">` tag to the end of the page is considered to be part of the link.

Comment: Thank you sir, I guess I just needed a fresh pair of eyes. When encountering this problem this was my first suspicion, and I even checked! Obviously I still looked it over anyways. Thank you.

Comment: Just get a better editor that highlights issues like this for you. Or run your code through HTML tidy.